# Simple text input, then results on label

Tags: android

I want to make my first android application , it would be a very basic utility. It would be like a text input where the users time the date they want , and on a label it would say how many days its been since that date.

EG: User type date ---> label shows how many days as past ---> user can save their entered date and app would show still show output from the label.

something as simple as that. How I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really wide. So welcome at Stack Overflow, where you can dream about code. But please be specific about your questions. We can't read your mind and though we want to help clear formulated question will naturally attracted well written and helpful answers :)

For the beginning I'd invite you do read a little bit in the official documentation.

Get some [orientation](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) here.

Or what about [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html):

> This class teaches you how to build your first Android app. You’ll
>   learn how to create an Android project and run a debuggable version of
>   the app. You'll also learn some fundamentals of Android app design,
>   including how to build a simple user interface and handle user input.

But please also read about the [background](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). I'm still referring to it. You can read as many examples if you like - if you haven't took a look under the hut you'll be lost.

Comment: Thank you , I will read these ! these could help understand more about the structure of an application !

Answer (score 0):

Please consult the official android docs:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html